# AngularDart (1) Template Cache Generator Transformer

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Does anyone have experience with AngularDart (1) template cache generator? I have set it up and it is aggregating the template strings, but they are not being used by the build version. The app is still making http requests to get the html files.

Here's what I have in pubspec.yaml:

```
transformers:
    - angular:
        generate_template_cache: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after debugging how AngularDart fetches from the template cache, I realized that I needed leading slashes on all my templateUrl values.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used AngularDart (v1) with pub unfortunately. You could try running `pub build` and manually inspecting the output files and see if has the template files inlined or not.

Comment: The template cache is definitely being created.  I can find it inline in the dart.js file.  Here's how it starts (from debug mode):

`C.Map_YmwAg = new H.ConstantStringMap(252, {"/packages/portal/client_brand/views/selected_brand_main.html": '<div ng-if="viewIsAuthorized">\n...`

The problem is it doesn't seem to be used.  The app is still making http calls to fetch the individual html files.